# Extract docker volumes from running container

Tags: docker, data-recovery, containers

My `/var/lib/docker/volumes` directory got accidentally lost. 
Some containers are running right now and the services aren't missing any files.
For example, I'm running a maven repo (Sonatype Nexus) and the libraries are still fine.

Is it possible to reveal the volumes of the running containers?

Containers running:

- Sonatype Nexus
- GitLab
- Minecraft-Server (unnecessary)

Answer (score 2):

If you lost **/var/lib/docker/volumes** directory and you don’t have lost any files this is mean that your sensitive information wasn't lost. That sounds good.

If container lost /var/lib/docker/volumes directory it will show message like this

> sh: getcwd: No such file or directory

and all files and folders in volume directory will be disappeared. You don't have any options to restore missing information from the container. You can only make data recovery in Linux. This is good link for beginning https://www.linux.com/learn/get-your-data-back-linux-based-data-recovery-tools

On the other hand, if you have not yet lost data it mean you do not use folder
**/var/lib/docker/volumes** directory

As per the official documentation, there are 2 ways in which you can manage volumes in Docker:

- Data volumes  - in this method used /var/lib/docker/volumes
- Mount a host directory as a data volume – in this method we mount an existing host folder in the Docker container

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Check where the data is stored with the command

```
docker inspect container_name
```

Look for the section

> "Mounts": [